# Are CloudEvents useful on gRPC framework?

Tags: protocol-buffers, grpc, cloudevents

We have been working on an existing application that emits event for consumer applications. Consumer applications interact with our application on gRPC.

We are evaluating [CloudEvent](https://cloudevents.io/) standards for our events. While we understand that it provides a standard envelope (with standard metadata attribute), we are wondering that its benefits on gRPC protocol will be limited.

Consumers use client stubs generated from .proto files and these stubs also generate static classes for these events.

Consumers cannot use generic [CloudEvents](https://cloudevents.io/) classes (from SDK). The only benefits they get is, if they want to send these event to their clients, they can serialize them and send them across. And their clients can use standard SDK classes to consume them.

Is this understanding correct or are we missing something?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please see if this thread helps.
https://github.com/cloudevents/sdk-go/issues/761

It basically allows you to get access to CloudEvent proto file. From there rest should be something that we might have to work with the respective SDK teams of CloudEvents